# How bean method is called in Apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Here is my bean

```
package beans;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class setFileNames {
    public String getCityName(Document document) {
        NodeList cities = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(
                "city");
        Element city = (Element) cities.item(0);
        String textContent = city.getTextContent();
            return textContent+".xml";
        }
}
```

And here is my route

```
public void configure ( )  throws java .lang .Exception {
    from ( uril1ap .get ("Sender  cFile  1") ).routeId ( "Sender_cFile_ l").split()
    .xpath ( "/ people/ person") .id ( "cSplitter_ l")
    .setHeader ( "CamelFileName")  .method ( beans.setFileNames.class)
    .id ( "cSetHeader_ l") .to ( uril1ap .get ( "Receiver_cFile_2") )
    .id ( "cFile_2") .process ( new  org .apache .camel . Processor ( )  
            { public void  process ( org .apache .carnel .Exchange  exchange)
    throws  Exception  {
    System .out .println ( "File rece ived : "
                                        + exchange .getIn ().getHeader ( "CamelFileName") ) ;
    }) .id ( "cProcessor_ l");
```

You may find some syntax issue in above route, but its working fine (copied not accurate code here)

want to know, as we can see `CamelFileName` bean is being used in route, which is an instance of class `setFileNames`, but how its calling  `getCityName` method of it in route ? How route is able to know which method to call and print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this statement that calls the Bean:

`.method ( beans.setFileNames.class)`

Although the argument is a bit strange in your case, you have various options what to pass to the `method` statement.

The most common are

- a Class `.method(MyBean.class)`
- a bean instance `.method(myBean)` that is created in the Route class
- by name `.method("myBean")` if the Bean is registered in the Application context

The method selection is quite simple in your case because there is only one method.

However, Camel has a quite "elaborate" algorithm to select the most suitable method in the Bean class.

If this algorithm selects the wrong method, you can explicitly call the method by name: `.method(MyBean.class, "myMethod")`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Camel invokes the public method in the class and, in this case, it also infers its argument `Document` as the message body, because no annotation (e.g. @Header, @ExchangeProperty etc) has been tied to the argument.

However, if your bean class has multiple public methods, so Camel tries to invoke the one whose argument matches the type of the message body. By finding multiple public methods with the argument having the same type, then it throws a runtime exception due to an ambiguity issue.

As @burki has mentioned, you may indicate the method you want to invoke in the route. But you can also mark one method in your bean class as the default by annotating it with `@Handler`.